# VB.NET Mathematical Operations (Large Additions)

Tags: vb.net, math

Hello I need some help trying to add two large numbers for example:
99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 + 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999,
im using biginteger for the operation but i get this error after too big of a value: (Value was either too large or too small for a Double)

here is my code:

```
    Dim one As System.Numerics.BigInteger = message.Text
    Dim two As System.Numerics.BigInteger = mykey.Text
    System.Numerics.BigInteger.TryParse(message.Text, two)
    sum.Text = (one + two).ToString
```

Comment: You have another question where someone suggested using `BigInteger` and you have obviously used that answer and yet you haven't accepted in in the thread.  Please do the right thing and accept answers that actually answer your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't actually make sense. I just tested the addition of those two `BigInteger` values like this:

```
Dim one As BigInteger = BigInteger.Parse("99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999")
Dim two As BigInteger = BigInteger.Parse("9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999")

Console.WriteLine((one + two).ToString)
Console.ReadLine()
```

and like this:

```
Dim str1 = "99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999"
Dim str2 = "9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999"
Dim one As BigInteger
Dim two As BigInteger

BigInteger.TryParse(str1, one)
BigInteger.TryParse(str2, two)

Console.WriteLine((one + two).ToString)
Console.ReadLine()
```

and it worked exactly as expected both times.

You really need to turn `Option Strict On` because your code is assigning `String` values to `BigInteger` variables, which is almost certainly what's causing your issue.  If you have a `String` that you want to convert to a `BigInteger` then you should either use `BigInteger.Parse` when the value is known to be valid or `BigInteger.TryParse` when it's not.

Your code doesn't really make sense because you first assume that implicit conversions will be OK but then you go ahead and use `TryParse` anyway.  It gets even more nonsensical because you use `TryParse` to populate what appears to be the wrong `BigInteger` variable.  You need to understand what your code is supposed to do before you write, otherwise you can end up with nonsense and have no idea that it doesn't do what you didn't know you wanted to do in the first place.

Comment: I just tried turning `Option Strict Off` and assigning those `Strings` directly to the `BigInteger` variables and it did indeed generate the exception you mentioned.  Of course, you could - and should - have specified which line the exception was thrown on.  It then would have needed no speculation or testing on our part.  Please do the right thing and provide ALL relevant information.  Where an error occurs is always relevant.